# Open mailto link in outlook(Web version)

Tags: outlook, mailto

I have mail in outlook(web version) which contains mailto link How should I open that link in outlook itself?

Comment: Sounds like Outlook Web Access (OWA) tries to be smart and prevents the `mailto:` protocol handler to do it's work and trigger Outlook as your mail client. I don't know if OWA can be convinced to leave mailto links alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found alternate way for mailto in OWA on this [blog](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/23a6f142-cabd-482c-a930-9ff200bb7941/owa-2010-mailto-links?forum=exchange2010).

Outlook Web Access expects a link such as this:

```
<a href='https://col125.mail.live.com/?page=Compose&to=someone@example.in'>someone@example.in</a>
```